# Prove formally that $a \le x \le a \Rightarrow x = a$ for $x, a \in \mathbb R$ not using contradiction.

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

> Prove formally that $a \le x \le a \Rightarrow x = a$ for $x, a \in \mathbb R$ not using contradiction.

I've been thinking how to prove the above statement not using contradiction.

My idea for a proof by contradiction is as follows: Suppose for contradiction that $x \neq a$ then the equality fails so $x = a$.

Suppose $a,x$ are integers or rational numbers, then proving the above statement for real numbers prove the statement for these classes of numbers also, since we can view them as real numbers ? Or should one be careful, since the ordering is defined different ?

Comment: An easy "find the error" to present to students: $a \leq x$ and $x \leq a$ gives $a - x \leq 0$ and $x - a \leq 0.$ Adding these last two equations gives $0 \leq 0,$ which is true for any choice of $a$ and $x,$ so $a \leq x \leq a$ always holds.

Answer (score 8):

$x\le a$ means $x<a$ or $x=a$. But $x\ge a$ means $x>a$ or $x=a$, so by [trichotomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_%28mathematics%29) it is not true that $x<a$. Hence $x=a$.

Comment: Trichotomy is another word for transitive ?

Comment: Wait a minute, trichotomy is a weak form of the law of excluded middle. I am not sure the OP meant to allow for this.

Answer (score 2):

$\le$ is a total order relation. One of the axioms of these is *antisymmetry*:

> If a ≤ b and b ≤ a then a = b

Apply this to $a\le x$ and $x\le a$.

Comment: So it is an axiom and not just a definition? Is the ordering of real numbers an extension of ordering for integers?

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with two definitions

**Definition:** Let $S$ be a set. An **order** on $S$ is a relation, denoted by $<$, with the following two properties

1. If $x\in S$ and $y\in S$ the one and only one of the statements$$x<y,\quad y<x,\quad x=y$$ is true.
2. If $x,y,z\in S$, if $x<y$ and $y<z$, then $x<z$.

**Definition:** An **ordered set** is a set $S$ in which order is defined.

---

Note that $\mathbb{R}$ is an ordered set.

We have $a,x\in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $a\le x \implies a<x$ or $a=x$ and $x\le a \implies x<a$ or $a=x$.

From the definition of order *one and only one* among the statement can be true and as $a=x$ is common to both implication that is the *one* statement which is true

Comment: How does one prove the order on the real numbers satisfy what you've said ?

Comment: @user111854: It is the definition of order.

Comment: Yes but the order has an implementation?

Comment: @user111854. I don't get your question?.

Comment: I mean one has to define when $a<b$ and then prove this definition meets the definition of an order.

Comment: Whatever be the definition of $<$ the theorem is still true provided $\mathbb{R}$ is still an ordered set.